# Application.xml not created in RAD7.5

Tags: websphere, enterprise, rad

I am using RAD7.5 while creating EAR project with level 5.0, I find that application.cml is not getting created. Is there a

Comment: application.xml is optional as of EE 5.  Why do you need one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by bkail, a number of DDs are optional in Java EE 5.0 (as it relies heavily on annotations).

If you want to explicitly create an application.xml and other DDs you can do so and the tooling provides you the facilities to create and maintain them.

Answer (score 6):

By default the checkbox "Generate Application.xml Deployment Descriptor" is not checked when creating an Enterprise Application in Rational Application Developer in the later versions of RAD. Check that box on the Enterprise Application Settings box.  it can be added after the fact by selecting the Enterprise `Project -> right click -> Java EE -> generate deployment` descriptor.